# Change CSS pseudo-element style in html tag

Tags: html, css, styling

## I'd like to modify a property of a pseudo-element in the html tag declaration.

I've tried to 'escape' the styleblock and reenter it (see below), but this doesn't work.  Is there some way to pass in an arbitrary attribute to the :hover pseudo-element of a given instance of an element?  I'd prefer to stick to CSS, if possible, but JS isn't out of the question.

## Wishful solution

For example, to override the color attribute of an instance of the myclass:hover pseudo-element, I'd like to do something like this:

CSS

```css
#myclass{color:#fff;}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul id="myclass" style="} #myclass:hover{color:{myColor};} #myclass{">...</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you can't overwrite inline styles in html by using CSS. You can however make changes to the inline style element using javascript or jquery

Comment: It's not often that you see an attempt to do CSS injection. +1 for thinking out of the box! However, don't do it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are need exactly, but I hope this will help you

CSS:

```
  myClass{
    color: yourColor;
  }
  myClass:hover
  {
     color: yourColorOnHover;
  }
```

JS

```
 $("#myClass").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "yourColor");
  });
```

To change class for element using JS( or JQUERY):
  if you have A and B class in CSS, then to change B instead of A

```
$(#myClass).removeClass("A");
  $(#myClass).addClass("B");
```